# Android: SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked

Tags: android, sqlite, database-locking

I can not figure out what is locking my database. This App is brand new in production and I can not even do the very first operation which is to add a user to the database. I have one single DatabaseHandler the does all DB ops. My Activity is calling a method in that handler. The method opens and closes the database. At the moment the only other operation that is database oriented is the creation of the DB.

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

......


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            Log.w(DATABASE, "Creating database at " + directoryPath + "/"
                    + DATABASE_NAME);
            db.execSQL(USER_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(PRODUCTS_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(INVOICE_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(INVOICE_PROD_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(CUSTOMER_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(BILLING_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(COMPANY_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(LOGO_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(TERMS_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(TEMPLATE_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(PREFS_TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(CURRENCY_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.d(DATABASE, "onCreate Created ALL Tables");
        }

......

    // WRITE VALUES TO DATABASE
        public void putUserData(String fUSERNAME, String fPASSWORD, String fEMAIL, String fFIRSTNAME, String fLASTNAME) {
            Log.d("DATABASE", "Received the following values to insert into the USER Table: " + fUSERNAME + ", " + fPASSWORD + ", " + fEMAIL + ", " + fFIRSTNAME + ", " + fLASTNAME);
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_USERNAME, fUSERNAME);
            cv.put(KEY_PASSWORD, fPASSWORD);
            cv.put(KEY_EMAIL, fEMAIL);
            cv.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, fFIRSTNAME);
            cv.put(KEY_LASTNAME, fLASTNAME);
            db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, cv);
            Log.d(DATABASE, "New User data written to Database " + fUSERNAME);
            db.close();
        }
}
```

I have inserted the Log.d to see where this is getting hung up.  The minute it calls the getWritableDatabase, the app crashes.

ActivityUserAccountCreate.java

```
public class ActivityCreateUserAccount extends Activity {

    static Context mContext;
    public ActivityCreateUserAccount(Context _mContext) {
    mContext = _mContext;
    }

    //Empty Constructor
    public ActivityCreateUserAccount(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_account);

...

DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
                    db.putUserData(fUSERNAME, fPASSWORD, fEMAIL, fFIRSTNAME, fLASTNAME);

..........
}
```

I have cut out the boring non related code. I have included the Context and Class. I am wondering if the Context is the issue?  Otherwise I use this exact code in my other database apps and have no problem. I can't figure what is different here.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you concerned, I have figured this out.  THe issue was the Context in ActivityUserAccountCreate.  I changed this from

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
```

to

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ActivityCreateUserAccount.this);
```

and then deleted the entire Context entry with mContext.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your context is not null.

Change `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext)` to `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this)`, otherwise set the mContext variable in the onCreate.

Comment: Thanks guy.  I actually just figured it out and posted the answer.